# How to deal with the url with value like root=, the parameter with key and without value?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, url-parameters

I have the problem just like the title. I know there is a `@RequesetParam` in spring mvc, it has a parameter `required=false`. But it failed when try to use it.

Actually I found the `@RequestParam` is useless. According to my trying, It always be O.K. using `@RequestParam(value="root", required=true)` where the URL is with/without `value=some value except blank`. 
So, I don't know what totally the `required=true` is. Then, whichever the `required=false` or `required=true`is, it throws exception with URL parameter like `...&root=`.

And my HandlerMapping & AdapterMapping are RequestMappingHandlerMapping and RequestMappingHandlerAdapter

the version of spring mvc is 3.2.4

Please tell me what's going on with the spring mvc?

Thanks advance:)

Comment: Exception will be thrown in case of the parameter missing in the request, and no need to set `required=true`, default value of `@RequestParam` is true.

Comment: Thank you so much. I confused about why the @RequestMapping can not deal with the URL parameter like &root=.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation:

> public abstract boolean required
>
> Whether the parameter is required. Default is true, leading to an
>   exception thrown in case of the parameter missing in the request.
>   Switch this to false if you prefer a null in case of the parameter
>   missing.
>
> Alternatively, provide a defaultValue, which implicitly sets this flag
>   to false.

so if the parameter is missing inside a request, you can decide whether an exception should have been thrown or not !

according to your question you are amazed why no exception does throw, It's because these two URL have different meaning :

> http://my-domain.ir:8080/your-project-name/main.html?p=something&root=
>
> http://my-domain.ir:8080/your-project-name/main.html?p=something

in the first case the value **root** exist but It doesn't have any value **But** in the second case it is missing, Your case meet the first condition and this is because no exception does throw .

```
//if you use the code below, in your case the root will get no value exactly like you define String root =""
@RequestParam("root") String root
```

I suggest you always use **@ModelAttribute** in spring and validate/not validate your **Bean** class variables as you wish with **JSR303** standard and receive your Parameter value using the GETTER/SETTER methods of that bean class.

Comment: Thank for your explaining in detail. My case is true for the first case. But, when submit the request with that url, I true received the exception `...MissingServletRequestParameterException`.

Comment: (you said that _this is because no exception does throw_). And this is my [spring mvc config](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7048848/). I have configed some error page. But If my url missing some parameters(not _doesn't have values_, such as the second case that without like `root=1`) and the server-side code with `required=true`, the same, it doesn't throw any error to me. I think it should has thrown the error to me.And why this could happen?

Comment: try to download this add-on and check exactly whether your URL is the one you expect it to be or not : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/ if you saw the root= prameter inside this tool, send me the full exception stack trace and I let me check it out !

Comment: The full URL is [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7050102/),and the full error is [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7050064/), this is my [java method](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7050139/) receiving the URL request.  And I found there are some parameters like `root=`, but they don't  arising errors, such as `txt=&txt1=`, the `txt,txt1,txt2,txt3` are the field in the Class ChannelTxt, but the `parentId` is just a parameter of integer in the URL. Thank you very  much :)

Comment: @EdgarZeng I saw the full URL, where is the question mark "?" after /Project/proadmin/channel/o_update.do ??? there should be a question mark and right after that the rest of the url, with no space ...

Comment: E,I don't know why there is a space between them. the submit form is like [this](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7053717/). The submit method is `POST`, is there any thing I ignored that make the space instead of `?` Thank you a lot:)

Answer (score 1):

You should use placeholder to get value in URL and use `@PathVariable` to get the values from url,

for example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customer/{customerId}/show", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showCustomerById(
            @PathVariable("customerId") int customerId) {
  ...
}
```

and the requested url will look like:

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/customer/1234/show
```

and if you want to pass parameter with above then, do like:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/customer/{customerId}/show", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showCustomerByIdAndName(
            @PathVariable("customerId") int customerId,
            @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name){
 ...
}
```

and the requested url will look like now:

```
   http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/customer/1234/show?name=myName
```

**Note:** the default value of required field is true, and if the parameter is not found then exception will raise.

Comment: It's a solution for my problem, but I want to know why the spring mvc cannot figure out the URL with `...&root=`, which doesn't have a value but not missing a parameter.

Comment: @EdgarZeng k, is there any space after `o_update.do` ? and which value you not getting ?

Comment: Until now I don't know why there is a space but a question mark `?` after the `o_update.do`, is there something special I haven't payed attention to it? I have paste the code in [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7053717/). Thank you both of you, very :)